# fixing <br> line when converting HTML <p> tag to email

Tags: javascript

I create a tag `<p id="email" >` and it contains many `<br/>` tag. The problem is if I convert it to email template it turns only one line. any suggestion to fix this problem? thank you

This is my code.

HTML code:

```
<div class="center">

    <div class="centerchild">
        <h3 class="headernote">Note Template</h3>
        <div class="centerchild">
            <p id="demo"></p>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="centerchild">
        <h3 class="headernote">Email Template</h3>
        <div class="centerchild">
            <p id=" subline"></p>
        </div>
        <div class="centerchild">
            <p id="email"></p>
        </div>
    </div>
```

JavaScript code:

```
var _selectedarraynote = doctemplate[_template]
var _selectedarrayemail = docemail[_template]

var _note = 0;
var text = "";
while (_selectedarraynote[_note]) {
    text += _selectedarraynote[_note] + "<br>";
    _note++;
}


var _email = 1;
var textemail = "";
while (_selectedarrayemail[_email]) {
    textemail += _selectedarrayemail[_email] + "<br />";
    _email++;
}

var _sub = 0;
var subemail = "";
while (_selectedarrayemail[_sub]) {
    subemail += _selectedarrayemail[_sub] + "<br/>";
    _sub--;
}


document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = text;
document.getElementById("email").innerHTML = textemail;
document.getElementById("subline").innerHTML = subemail;
```

In web this is the output:

```
Service Reference Number: 
Member's Name: 
Provider's Name: 
Provider's Cell Phone Number: 
Provider's Office Phone Number: 
Provider's Title: 
Time Provider Submitted the Request: 
Provider's Time Zone: 
How is this Provider involved in the care of this member?
```

but when I convert it to an email its only one line.

```
Service Reference Number:test Member's Name: Provider's Name: Provider's Cell Phone Number: Provider's Office Phone Number: Provider's Title: Time Provider Submitted the Request: Provider's Time Zone: Preferred Timeframe range and date: How is this Provider involved in the care of this member?
```

Comment: Where is the code that is "converting it to an email"?  If the email template isn't HTML, then HTML tags like `<br />` aren't going to be processed.  If your email template is ASCII text, you probably need `\n` for newline instead.

Comment: function myMail() {
    try {
        let a = document.getElementById("rmdName").value;
        let b = document.getElementById("email").innerText;
        let c = document.getElementById("subti").innerText;
        var mail = "mailto:" + a + "?subject=" + c + "&body=" + b;
        var mlink = document.createElement('a');
        mlink.setAttribute('href', mail);
        mlink.click();
    } catch (e) {
        alert(e);
        // act on any error that you get
    }
}

Comment: that's the code for converting into email. the /n is not working also,

Comment: my email is outlook by the way